# What is the type hint for a class reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I am looking at [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) and cannot find a description of how to type hint a class reference. Are class references declared as Callables as shown below?

```py
from typing import Callable

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = 'Hello'

    def display(self):
        print(self.s)

x: Callable[[], SomeClass] = SomeClass

instance = x()
instance.display()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you only care that `x` is *a* class, you would just use `type` (or some other appropriate metaclass).

```
x: type = SomeClass
```

If `x` should be `SomeClass` or one of its descendants, use `typing.Type`

```
x: typing.Type[SomeClass] = SomeClass
```

If `x` has to be *exactly* `SomeClass` (for whatever reason), I think `typing.TypeVar` is the appropriate choice.

```
x: typing.TypeVar('SomeClass', SomeClass) = SomeClass
```

Comment: Your first two examples are absolutely correct. However, your 3rd example isn't actually PEP-484 compliant: `TypeVar(...)` isn't a valid type and is more of a "type constructor" you'd use to create a type variable (which *is* a valid type!). So you'd do `T = TypeVar('T')` or `T = TypeVar('T', bound=SomeClass)` then use `T` as a type hint -- but only within functions or classes that are generic w.r.t. `T`. So, things like `x: Type[T] = SomeClass` aren't actually too useful: `T` would need to be always bound to exactly `SomeClass`, and you might as well not bother with generics at that point.